# How do I make a function that fires a bullet from the gun in a straight line to the right in c#?

Tags: c#, graphics, unity-game-engine

First: I'm a real noob.

Here's my code for my shoot function:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float fireRate = 0; // makes it a single fire per click weapon
public float Damage = 10;
public LayerMask notToHit; // tells us what is valid for being hit by the weapon
public float Range = 100;

float timeToFire = 0;
Transform firePoint;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake () 
{
    firePoint = transform.FindChild ("firePoint");
    if (firePoint == null) 
    {
        Debug.LogError ("No FirePoint object found as a child of the cannon");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
            Shoot ();
            if (fireRate == 0)
            {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1"))
                    {
                            Shoot ();
                    }
            } 
            else 
            {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire) {
                            timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
                            Shoot ();
                    }
            }
}
void Shoot ()
{
    Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
    Vector2 target = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, [firePoint.position.y + Range]);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePoint, notToHit);
    Debug.DrawLine (firePointPosition, target);

}
```

I just want it to draw a line (cause I'm still learning) from my firePoint object (at the mouth of my cannon) to a point +100 units on the Y axis (Range = 100).

I'm getting following c# errors:

1) Assets/Gun.cs(47,69): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type

2) Assets/Gun.cs(47,98): error CS8032: Internal compiler error during parsing, Run with -v for details

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, like I said, I'm new here.

I've posted the full script in the original post

Comment: Which lines is at specific there are creating the errors? 
IS it  Vector2 target = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, [firePoint.position.y + Range]); ?
And if it is. What if you remove Range and try to compile your code?
Vector2 target = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y); ?

Comment: Yes, that is my line 47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Noctis already wrote the Vector2 target line is wrong. It should be like this

```
Vector2 target = new Vector2 ( firePoint.position.x, (firePoint.position.y + Range));
```

After that you say you have another compile error, but it is an error on line 48, so the Raycast call is wrong. 
To call the Raycast you will have to do something like this:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Origin, Direction);
// So your code should be 
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePoint, DIRECTION);
```

This means you will have to create another Vector2 which defines the direction of your "shoot line".

I attached a link which describe the call to Raycast
[See the reference here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

Please try to update your code and come back

Since i can see you only want to draw the line right now you should comment out you error proned code. So you code should look like this:

```
void Shoot ()
{
    Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
    Vector2 target = new Vector2 (firePoint.position.x, (firePoint.position.y + Range));
    // No need to do the ray casting right now 
    // RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (firePoint, notToHit);
    Debug.DrawLine (firePointPosition, target);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Now I can proceed with figuring out how this is supposed to work :)

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as 'answered'. 
Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

This line seems very fishy to me :

```
  Vector2 target = new Vector2 ( firePoint.position.x
                               , [firePoint.position.y + Range]
                               );
```

you're passing something that looks like an array to the new function, this is why it's complaining I believe.

Did you try to say :

```
  Vector2 target = new Vector2 ( firePoint.position.x 
                               , (firePoint.position.y + Range)
                               );
```

Comment: Yes: that changes the errors as follows:

1) Assets/Gun.cs(48,46): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Physics2D.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' has some invalid arguments

AND THE SECOND ERROR:

2) Assets/Gun.cs(48,46): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Transform' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector2'

Comment: @PaulNowak Based on your error here, this answer actually does fix the first error, but it seems to me that you doing the call to Raycast wrong.

Comment: um, ok...I believe you, but what do I do about it?

Comment: If I might step in here, @PaulNowak, it appears you are trying to run before you can walk. Do you know what a Vector is? What ray casting is? How transforms work?

Comment: Honestly, not really.  I'm following a tutorial, but it's for firing at wherever the mouse is pointing.  I just want the gun to fire in a straight line along the y axis, so I'm trying to modify it.

If you know of a tutorial to fire a weapon that way, I'm happy to watch it and start over :)

Comment: @PaulNowak hmmm ... maybe you should find a simpler tutorial then. Also, usually `x` axis is right left and `y` is up down ...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that; wasn't thinking (shame face).

Now that I can correctly pick the point I want based on the starting point the rest of the tutorial should be better.

Thank again for your help (never did anything with shooting before)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the firing question:
I assume you are using sprites and on a 2D environment since you are using Vector2. If that is the case you may want to either apply a force or directly change the "bullet" transform using the [Vector2.right](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-right.html) or even the [Transform.forward](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html), the latter will change depending on where your character is facing.
If you are going to [instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) the bullet prefab in the firePointPosition transform I would advice on just applying a force to the prefab the instantiation.
Something like:

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab; //Initialize it either by drag&drop from the editor or through code
private float bulletSpeed; // self explanatory

/* Rest of the code*/

GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePointPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.right * bulletSpeed);
// or
bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed);
```